# Getting nothing from webservice

Tags: php, .htaccess, webhooks

I'm writing an API and I need to get some data from a webhook ( Shopify ).

Yesterday it was working but it suddenly stopped even tho my `.htaccess` file looks the same as another copy I was working on.

The webhook is addressed as:

> http://mywebsite/API-NEW/insertOrder.service

Here are some pieces from the `.htaccess`:

```
## default index file

  DirectoryIndex index.php

## rewrite everything else to API.php

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^/]+)(?:/API-NEW)
  RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\.(service|test)$   index.php?action=$1&debug=$2&shop=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [nc,qsa,L]
```

Here is my `index.php`:

```
<?php

require_once 'configs.php';
require_once 'helpers/helpers.php';
require_once 'helpers/io_helpers.php';

$date = date(DATE_RFC2822);

file_put_contents('debug/debug_info.txt', 'Request started', FILE_APPEND);

if (in_array($_GET['action'],array('insertOrder','updateOrder'))){
    writeToDebug($date . " --> New: " . $_GET['action']);

    getRequest();
}
```

It's not writing anything to `debug/debug_info.txt` so I'm kind of losing my s*** atm.

Help please?

Comment: did you check folder/file permissions? see if error reporting spews anything out http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and check your logs also. Plus, how are you executing the `getRequest()` and `writeToDebug()` functions?

Comment: *"The webhook is addressed as: h.t.t.p://Mywebsite"* - you do mean `http://Mywebsite` *correct?*

Comment: It's not getting to that part.. I'm checking if it's working if it prints something to the debug file but it's not

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes but SO would actually make that an hyperlink . And how do I get those errors to my debug file?

Comment: you undid my edit http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35659912/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was a typo mistake in one of the required files.

It turns out this was giving an error:

```
function getProductsTable($csvFile = __DIR__ . '/../products.csv', $delimiter = ',')
#Somehow assigning csvFile like that doesn't work
```

Who would've guessed...